# Jump to, not call, a function in C without using stack (callback function)

Tags: callback, stack, interrupt, goto

I have an interrupt in C that will call a "callback" function. CallBack has only one line of executable code, it calls YetAnotherFunction.

Rather then have CallBack use the normal C calling convention (where it pushes a return address onto the stack then jumps to YetAnotherFunction,) is there a way I can JUMP to YetAnotherFunction without the push?

Interrupt, CallBack, and YetAnotherFunction are in separate files and placed into the executable at link time.

Reasoning...

I have an interrupt that gets called one hundred times a second. It in turn calls YetAnotherFunction 4 times a sec.

I want to make the interrupt more universal, so I want to create a generalized CallBack function. In one project, CallBack, will call YetAnotherFunction. In other projects, It will simply return without doing any work.

This, because I want to place the interrupt routine in my universal library, and Callback can be unique in each project.

Currently, within CallBack, I use the C structures to call YetAnotherFunction, but it occurs to me that will push the return address onto the stack, and require a second "bounce" when returning from YetAnotherFunction. While this isn't much, it is offending my OCD.

Is there a way I can, from within CallBack, just jump to YetAnotherFunction without pushing an address into the stack? In this way, when returning from YetAnotherFunction, it returns directly to the interrupt caller.

Thanks for your help, Mark.

PS, must I declare either CallBack, or YetAnotherFunction as interrupts? Are there any hidden 'gotchas' I should think about when calling functions from within interrupt handlers?

Also, I may be using the term callback incorrectly, but I think you get the idea.

Thx. M.

Answer (score 1):

Just write good C code.

```c
int second(int x);

int first(int x)
{
    return second(x);
}
```

Any respectable compiler will detect the tail-call, and if appropriate optimizations are enabled will emit a "jump" instruction instead of a call. E.g.

```
first:
    jmp second
```

https://godbolt.org/z/9s3iPt

Comment: There you go. I was unaware of that, thanks @Jonathon. I will test it and let you know. To be specific, I am using the compiler included in the Code Composer Studio from TI creating code for their Piccolo TMS320F28027. It does have several levels of optimizations (most of which I have turned off so I can better understand assembly level debugging while single stepping.) I will try various levels of optimization. MM.